# Disk space not decrease after delete cassandra data

Tags: linux, server, cassandra, delete-row, diskspace

About 2 weeks ago I deleted about 700GB of cassandra data. But until now the disk space is still not free. I know that with gc_grace_second and default_time_to_live when expired will delete data. And nodetool compactionstats still has pending tasks.

```
   CREATE TABLE ywulzsrdphjlbgoksmnqoliktcmrlcybidcw (
       key text,     
       column1 text,
       value text,
       PRIMARY KEY (key, column1) )
   WITH COMPACT STORAGE
   AND bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.100000
   AND caching='{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}' 
   AND comment=''
   AND dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000
   AND gc_grace_seconds=1
   AND read_repair_chance=0.000000
   AND default_time_to_live=0
   AND speculative_retry='NONE'
   AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms=0
   AND compaction={'class':'LeveledCompactionStrategy'}
   AND compression={'sstable_compression': 'LZ4Compressor'};
```

Comment: This is a recipe for "ghost data": `gc_grace_seconds=1`.  I wrote an article a little while back detailing why setting `gc_grace_seconds` too low is a bad idea: https://medium.com/building-the-open-data-stack/tombstones-and-ghost-data-dont-have-to-be-scary-with-these-tips-and-tricks-from-datastax-48f3c275b05a

Answer (score 0):

Using TimeWindowCompactionStrategy may help you to have the compaction process being triggered more frequently compare with your current compaction strategy which is "LeveledCompactionStrategy".

Alternatively, you can use "nodetool compact keyspace/table" to forcefully trigger compaction process on the keyspace or table on which you had deleted data.